# Getting images from Cocoapod's xcassets doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcasset

I am using the 1Password Pod and the GCast pod and they both have xcassets files with the assets they want you to use. When I create a button in IB and assign it the name of one of the images in the xcassets file, the correct image shows up but on run-time i get a debug error of: `Could not load the "onepassword-button" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.myApp.App"`

Any idea what i need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to resolve this that I've found is to specify the image programmatically, not in Interface Builder:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: OnePasswordExtension.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "OnePasswordExtensionResources.bundle/onepassword-button", inBundle: bundle,
                    compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

Note that you still need to specify the full path to the resource bundle in `UIImage` initializer, as the `bundle` value is not the resource bundle itself, but the container framework bundle.

Comment: This is wrong answer. There is a correct one: https://github.com/agilebits/onepassword-app-extension/issues/248#issuecomment-135042466